# Linux Wildcard Random instead of Alphabetical Order?

Tags: linux, wildcards

Is it possible to use the `*` operator in Linux randomly instead of in alphabetical order? For example, if I run `cat *`, it will use `cat` in alphabetical order. Is it possible for it to run `*` in random instead of in alphabetical order?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: If you explain what you are actually trying to achieve someone might think of an alternative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No for the `*` wildcard itself, as far as I know, but depending on what do you want to do, you can indeed achieve it other ways.

eg. for a a `cat *`, if you mean going through the file list randomly, you can do

> cat $(ls -1 |sort -R)

Comment: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/128985/108618).